# babel, beamer and nag conflict

Tags: beamer, babel, nag

With the MWE below, I experience some problem. As shown, the MWE compiles fine.
If I change from book to beamer, I receive the "TeX capacity exceeded" error.
If I comment out either nag or babel, it compiles fine again. What is going on here?

```
%\documentclass{beamer} 
\documentclass{book}    
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}      % Require syntax analyzis

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xkeyval}    % Allow to use key-value pairs in arguments of macros
\usepackage{listingsutf8}   % Use program listings

    \usepackage[english,magyar]{babel}

\makeatletter
    \define@key{MEMacros}{language}{\def\ME@language{#1}}
    \define@key{MEMacros}{options}{\def\ME@options{#1}}
%%%Usage \MESourceFile[keys]{source file}{caption}{label}
    \newcommand\MESourceFileNew[4][]{
        \setkeys{MEMacros}{language={[ANSI]C},options={}, ,#1}% 
            \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
                \lstinputlisting[language={\ME@language},\ME@options,label=#4, name=#4]{#2}}
            \x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \MESourceFileNew[language={[ANSI]C}, options={numbers=left}
    ]{HelloWorld.c}{caption}{lst:HelloWorld.c}

\end{document}

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Comment: Avoid `nag`; it does worse than it would solve. In any case, it should be loaded *before* `\documentclass`.

Comment: @egreg Hmm. The intended functionality is OK. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: In this case, `nag` hangs at the evaluation of `caption`, probably because it doesn't understand the redefinition made by `beamer`. I find  `nag` useless in general even if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in interaction with the `magyar` option: this is what I get if I add `\errorcontextlines=100` to the example file

```
\nag@@warning@xliii  ->\nag@captioncheck 
                                         \nag@haslabeltrue 
\@@magyar@orig@label ->\nag@@warning@xliii 
                                           \nag@@label@xliii 
\@@magyar@labelb #1->\@@magyar@orig@label 
                                          {#1}\begingroup \c@page \@m \edef ...

\@@magyar@labelb #1->\@@magyar@orig@label {#1}
                                              \begingroup \c@page \@m \edef ...

\@@magyar@labelb #1->\@@magyar@orig@label {#1}
                                              \begingroup \c@page \@m \edef ...
```

So the problem is in how the label is checked in the case of `listings` and in the interaction with the redefinitions that both `magyar.ldf` and `beamer` do on `\label`.

I don't think there is a sensible way for solving this conflict; following all the juggles performed by `magyar.ldf` is very complicated.

The best is to forget about `nag`.